# For apps targeting Android11, the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

My app is in Play store, today I received a important email that I have to fix this in next update otherwise they will remove my app from playstore . Can anyone tell me how can I fix this ..
thanks in advance

> We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage
> flag in the manifest file of one or more of your app bundles or APKs.
>
> Developers with apps on devices running Android 11+ must use scoped
> storage to give users better access control over their device storage.
> To release your app on Android 11 or newer after 5 May, you must
> either:
>
> Update your app to use more privacy-friendly best practices, such as
> the storage access framework or Media Store API Update your app to
> declare the All files access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in
> the manifest file, and complete the All files access permission
> declaration in Play Console from 5 May Remove the All files access
> permission from your app entirely For apps targeting Android 11, the
> requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored. You must use the
> All files access permission to retain broad access.
>
> Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a
> permitted use will be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able
> to publish updates.

```
Manifest.xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.YMusic">
            <activity android:name="com.developer_ashu.ymusic.PlaySong"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:parentActivityName="com.developer_ashu.ymusic.MainActivity">
    
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.developer_ashu.ymusic.MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver android:name=".Notification.NotificationReceiver"/>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>



MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   ArrayList<song_info> listSongs = new ArrayList<song_info>();
   private MySongAdapter mySongAdapter ;
    private  String[] itemsAll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);


        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                      loadSongs();
                    }
                    @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {


                    }
                    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                     }
                }).check();
    }

  private void loadSongs(){
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
      String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,null,selection,null,null);
      if (cursor != null){
          while(cursor.moveToNext()){
              String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
              String author = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
              String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

              listSongs.add(new song_info(title,author,url));
          }
      }
      mySongAdapter = new MySongAdapter(listSongs);
      listView.setAdapter(mySongAdapter);
  }

    private class MySongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<song_info> myListSongs;

        public MySongAdapter(ArrayList<song_info> myListSongs) {
            this.myListSongs = myListSongs;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myListSongs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return myListSongs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return (long) position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView,textView1;
            Button button;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,parent,false);
            song_info song = myListSongs.get(position);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            textView.setText(song.Title);
            textView1.setText(song.Author);
            button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if ( button.getText().equals("STOP")){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    button.setText("PLAY");
                }
                else   {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        Log.v("MainActivity.this",song.songUrl);
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(song.songUrl);
                        // After this line it throws an error if I remove requestLegacyStorage from manifest
//                        Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) -- this is the error
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        button.setText("STOP");

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in playingSong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }
}




song_info.java
public class song_info {
    String Title = null;
    String Author = null;
    String songUrl = null;

    public song_info(String title, String author, String songUrl) {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        this.songUrl = songUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The message states what you need to do, `Android 11+ must use scoped storage` so make the appropriate changes to use scoped storage

Answer (score 3):

if your targetSdk is not 30 you can keep using that flag
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
And you don' t have to do anything.
But developers should do targetSdk = 30  in November.
I share answer which came from google:

"you can continue to use requestLegacyExternalStorage after May 5th since you are not targeting Android 11. You do not need to do anything before May 5th."

In our application targetSdk = 29 and we use requestLegacyExternalStorage. If you are in the same condition, you don' t have to do anything for now.

Answer (score 2):

Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute. This flag allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files. After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag.

solution :
is to migrate from legacyExternalStorage to Scooped Storage to support Android API  level
11+
useful Links to understand how the Scoope storage work
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage
https://www.androidcentral.com/what-scoped-storage